Backup Dbeaver with postgres
I'm tring to apply backup using DBeaver with postgres:
1: Create backup:

2:

3: I try apply restore on another database and get this:

this is the error pg_restore: error: did not find magic string in file header
what's wrong???

This question is maybe better suited for Server Fault, but in any case:
You've exported your database as a .sql file, which is a plain text file containing queries.
On the import screen, you selected the custom format, which checks to see if the input file starts with a few specific bytes (the same as how a .gz file starts with 0x1F 0x8B), the mentioned "magic string". Since your .sql doesn't start with that, the error is thrown.
Select plain while importing to use your .sql file.
A description of all formats you can import and export with are listed in DBeaver's documentation.
